# req ist not defined even when it's filled with values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im updating some of my data inside my database with a `REST API`. Therefore I created a route with `POST` (I use it for both) like this and call it with a submit button:

```
router.post('/add/edit/update', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  var sql = 'UPDATE gerichte SET gericht = ' + reg.body.gericht + ', Kalorien = ' + reg.body.Kalorien + ', preis_id = ' + req.body.preis + ', kategory_id = ' + req.body.kategorie + ', allergene = ' + req.body.allergene + ' WHERE g_id = ' + req.body.g_id + ';';
  conn.query(sql, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
  res.redirect('/add/edit');  // redirect to user form page after inserting the data
});
```

But I always get the error `req not found` when I sumbit the form. I tried printing the `req object` but it's filled nicely:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  g_id: '1',
  gericht: 'Schnitzel mit Pommes',
  Kalorien: '1400',
  preis: '1',
  kategorie: '5',
  allergene: 'dsd'
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `req` (with a lower-case Q), not `reg` (with lower-case G).

---

Change

```js
var sql = 'UPDATE gerichte SET gericht = ' + reg.body.gericht + ', Kalorien = ' + reg.body.Kalorien + ', preis_id = ' + req.body.preis + ', kategory_id = ' + req.body.kategorie + ', allergene = ' + req.body.allergene + ' WHERE g_id = ' + req.body.g_id + ';';
```

to

```js
var sql = 'UPDATE gerichte SET gericht = ' + req.body.gericht + ', Kalorien = ' + req.body.Kalorien + ', preis_id = ' + req.body.preis + ', kategory_id = ' + req.body.kategorie + ', allergene = ' + req.body.allergene + ' WHERE g_id = ' + req.body.g_id + ';';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sql = 'UPDATE gerichte SET gericht = ' + reg.body.gericht + ', Kalorien = ' + reg.body.Kalorien + ', preis_id = ' + req.body.preis + ', kategory_id = ' + req.body.kategorie + ', allergene = ' + req.body.allergene + ' WHERE g_id = ' + req.body.g_id + ';';
```

The error might be reg not defined because:
In the above line of your code, you've been using reg.body, when there is no reg defined.
Kindly correct it and see if the issue is resolved or not.